# Decrease username length in Django 1.10 and django-registration 2.2

Tags: django, django-registration

how can I decrease the username length?
I am using Django 1.10 and django-registration 2.2.
I am using the ["HMAC activation workflow"](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.2/hmac.html) and the base form class ["registration.forms.RegistrationFormUniqueEmail"](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.2/forms.html).
I am new to Django and a little bit overwhelmed.
Do I have to write a complete new custom user model or is there a simple solution?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `decrease the username length`? Change the required username length on registration?

Comment: change the maximum allowed username length to 20 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to to is extend django-registration's [form class](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.2/forms.html) and add custom field [validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/), something like that:

```
from django import forms

from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail


class RegistrationForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    def clean_username():
        data = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if len(date) < 20:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username has to be longer then 20 characters.")

        return data
```

You then have to override the views and make then use the form above:

> By default, this workflow uses registration.forms.RegistrationForm as
>   its form class for user registration; this can be overridden by
>   passing the keyword argument form_class to the registration view.